# related to z scores

Tags: normal-distribution

i know that it is related to z scores and i know the numbers given, I'm just not sure how to apply the formula for this.

Costumers in a department store are normally distributed with a mean age of 32.3 years and a standard deviation of 9.7 years.

a) What is the probability that the next customer that enters the store will be in their twenties?

b) What is the probability that 2 of the next 3 customers will be in their twenties?

Comment: do you know the pdf of a normal distribution? That may help you

Comment: What does "in their twenties" mean ? Should the age be *exactly* $20$ ? Should it be between $20$ and $29$ ?

Comment: i have the range of 20-29 for my x value